# Accessing a structure array through a pointer

Tags: c++

I have a class with a structure for its position:

```
class thing
{
    void setCoOrds(int, int, int);

    string name;
    struct location
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
    } coOrd;
};
```

Then in a function I created an array of type thing.

```
int main()
{
    thing * p_myThings = new thing[5];
    // call array element here to use setCoOrds()
    delete p_myThings;

    return 0; 
}
```

From the main function how would I access, lets say, thing element [3] so that I can use its .setCoOrds() function?

Comment: Do you just want `p_myThings[3].setCoOrds(1,2,3)`? Or am I missing something? (In any case, prefer `std::vector` to dangerous pointer-juggling.)

Comment: You must use delete[] here else you'll leak memory!

Comment: @Mike Seymour Oh, looks like I was over complicating it. I was thinking pointer to arrays and how to have to add to the pointer etc. silly me.

Comment: Where is objective-c++?

Comment: I've removed your `objective-c` tag.  Also this arguably is a very rudimentary question best served in a _Welcome to c/c++_ 101 book or equivalent tutorial rather than being on this site

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
p_myThings[3].setCoOrds
```

Also the

```
setCoOrds
```

is private by default which will not allow you to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    thing * p_myThings = new thing[5];

    p_myThings[3].setCoOrds(42,21,0);

    delete[] p_myThings; // use delete[] for arrays btw

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Don't post code-only answers.  Explain the code's behaviour and changes in order for others to understand

Comment: @MickyDuncan Yep i highly thought about that, but since it's a pure syntax question, i didn't find anything else to say except "this is how you do it" which is kind of a pointless statement :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that member function

```
void setCoOrds(int, int, int);
```

has public access control. In this case you can use the following constructions

```
p_myThings[3].setCoOrds( x, y, z );
```

or

```
( *( p_myThings + 3 ) ).setCoOrds( x, y, z );
```

or

```
( p_myThings + 3 )->setCoOrds( x, y, z );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
p_myThings[3].setCoOrds(x, y, z);
```

And for deleting pointer arrays you should use delete[] not delete